I can not see this screen shot
This is my question

I do not understand why, now I can not see this screen shot.
When I click the link, I get

How can I see screen shots?
PS. Now I can see all images.

I can see all images OK  on the link you showed. I can only suggest to clear all the cache of your browser and see if this fixes it or try different browser and see.

See here for same issue https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/399031/images-from-i-sstatic-net-only-work-for-me-after-being-accessed-from-another-ip

Notice also that stackexchange have been doing lots of changes to the way they store and upload images. This is why SEUploader for example no longer works. So what you see could be related. I never saw this problem myself but it looks like other did see it from the link given above. So this looks like stackexchange issue and not just for this Mathematica site.

@Nasser Thank you very much. You are right. Stackexchange issue.

@azerbajdzan Thank you very much.
